# Cumulative sum over time window frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
i = pd.date_range('2021-09-01', periods=8, freq='11H50min')
ts = pd.DataFrame({'animal_code_1':['A','B','C','A','A','B','','B'],
                   'animal_code_2':['AA','BB','','AA','AA','BB','DD','BB'],
                   'deaths': [1, 3, 1, 0,4,5,3,2]}, index=i)
```

`animal_code_1`and `animal_code_2` are always diferente both referes to a unique animal in a experiment, sometimes you can have both numbers, sometimes just one of them( the other is nan);

**what I expect as result:***

```
g=pd.DataFrame({'animal_code_1':['A','B','C',''],
                'animal_code_2':['AA','BB','','DD'],
                'day1_death':[1,3,1,0],'day2_death':[5,3,1,0],
                'day4_death':[5,10,1,3]})
```

So, what I need is cumulative sum od deaths during(in this case) `day1,day2 and day4`

**What I tried:**

```
table = pd.pivot_table(ts, values='deaths', index=['frogs'],
                    columns=[i], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

But this is not what I expected.

I know theres a cumsum function, but I didn´t manage to make it work.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Your expected result is not a commutative sum. e-g, for  B, BB values should be 3, 8, 10 for days columns whereas you have 3, 3, 10. How ???

Comment: 8 happens in day3. I wanted day1 day2  day4

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ts.reset_index(inplace=True)
ts['index'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['index'])
ts['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['index'].dt.date)
ts = ts.groupby(['date', 'animal_code_1', 'animal_code_2'])['deaths'].sum().reset_index()
ts['dummy'] = ts['date'].dt.day
ts['dummy'] = 'day' + ts['dummy'].astype(str) + '_death'

ts = ts.pivot_table(index=['animal_code_1', 'animal_code_2'], columns='dummy', values='deaths').fillna(0)
ts.reset_index(inplace=True)

#days_cols
days_cols = [col for col in list(ts) if col.startswith('day')]

ts[days_cols] = ts[days_cols].cumsum(axis=1)

ts = ts[['animal_code_1', 'animal_code_2', 'day1_death', 'day2_death', 'day4_death']]
ts[['day1_death', 'day2_death', 'day4_death']] = ts[['day1_death', 'day2_death', 'day4_death']].astype(int)
print(ts)
ts = ts.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
       animal_code_1 animal_code_2  day1_death  day2_death  day4_death
0                          DD           0           0           3
1             A            AA           1           5           5
2             B            BB           3           3          10
3             C                         1           1           1
```

Comment: almost this, but still incorrect:  its showing AA at day with 3, should be 5

Comment: Edited, check it now.